# How to add my own created drop down menu to theme?

Tags: wordpress

I have created my own drop down menu in html&css. So,anyone can guide me how, i can add my self made dropdown menu to my own custom WordPress theme ?
I don't want to use any Plugin because it would not give me same look as my own drop down menu.

Thanks In advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its not clear if you already have any [register_nav_menus](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_nav_menus). If you have any registered menu, you need to call it through [wp_nav_menu](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nav_menu) and use you own css in style.css of your theme. After adding your css in `style.css`, you need to check this css hierarchy of Unordered List generated by `wp_nav_menu`.

You can also check `Menu_Item_CSS_Classes` section in `wp_nav_menu` documentation.

If your theme don't have any `register_nav_menus`, add this in your `functions.php` file to make it more managale in future.

Answer (score 0):

Pretty straightforward. Somewhere in your theme you should see a function called `wp_nav_menu`:

```
<?php wp_nav_menu(); ?>
```

This is the default navigation. Replace it with your own HTML, and add the CSS to the `style.css` file. If there's any JavaScript, you'll obviously need to include that on the site, too.